# Failing to do fitting with non linear fitting methods (nlsLM, nlxb and wrapnls)

Tags: r, dplyr, nls, non-linear-regression

I have a `nls` `fitting` task that I wanted to do with R.
My first attempt to do  this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909690/trouble-when-adding-3rd-fitting-parameter-in-nls) and as @Roland pointed out

*"The point is that complex models are difficult to fit. The more so, the less the data supports the model until it become impossible. You might be able to fit this, if you had extremely good starting values."*

**I can agree with @Roland but if `excel` can do this fitting why not `R` cannot do?**

Basically this fitting can be done with Excel's GRG Nonlinear solver but the process is very time consuming and sometimes fitting is not good. (since there are a lots of data in reality).

here is my sample data.frame. I would like to fit each `set` group with the model provided at below,

```
set.seed(12345)
    set =rep(rep(c("1","2","3","4"),each=21),times=1)
    time=rep(c(10,seq(100,900,100),seq(1000,10000,1000),20000),times=1)
    value <- replicate(1,c(replicate(4,sort(10^runif(21,-6,-3),decreasing=FALSE))))
    data_rep <- data.frame(time, value,set)

     > head(data_rep)
            #    time        value set
            #1     10 1.007882e-06   1
            #2    100 1.269423e-06   1
            #3    200 2.864973e-06   1
            #4    300 3.155843e-06   1
            #5    400 3.442633e-06   1
            #6    500 9.446831e-06   1
            *      *       *         *
```

## attempt 1

I already posted a question to here [trouble-when-adding-3rd-fitting-parameter-in-nls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909690/trouble-when-adding-3rd-fitting-parameter-in-nls)

Basically the problem is that I wanted to do fitting in grouped data and doing prediction based on the fitting coefficients.

I used `nlsLM` from `library(minpack.lm)` I got an error

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper) : 
>     singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

which was at first glance maybe the model error or my starting values were not good in accordance to @Roland. On the other hand, I could fit this model with only two fitting parameters. The problem arises when I wanted to add `third` parameter to the fitting function.

## attempt 2

In that post [trouble-when-adding-3rd-fitting-parameter-in-nls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909690/trouble-when-adding-3rd-fitting-parameter-in-nls) by following @G. Grothendieck suggestion, I tried `nlxb` from `nlmrt` package and fixed one of the parameter `d` to `d=32` and do the fitting as follows;

```
formula = value~Ps*(1-exp(-2*f*time*exp(-d)))*1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma))*exp(-(d-d_ave)^2/(2*sigma))*d_step

d_step <- 1
f <- 1e9
d <- 32    
library(plyr)
library(nlmrt)
get.coefs <- function(data_rep) {
fit <-  nlxb(formula ,
              data = data_rep,
              start=c(d_ave=44,sigma=12,Ps=0.5),
              lower=c(d_ave=25,sigma=2,Ps=0.5),
              upper=c(d_ave=60,sigma=15,Ps=1),
              trace=TRUE)
}

fit <- dlply(data_rep, c("set"), .fun = get.coefs)   # Fit data grouped by "set"

#    > fit
#    $`1`
#    nlmrt class object: x 
#    residual sumsquares =  1.474e-07  on  21 observations
#        after  12    Jacobian and  13 function evaluations
#      name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      #gradient    JSingval   
#    d_ave            42.0126            NA         NA         NA  #-7.082e-15    0.001733  
#    sigma            12.8377            NA         NA         NA   #2.408e-15   1.289e-19  
#    Ps              0.973223            NA         NA         NA    #9.33e-15    3.37e-20  
#    
#    $`2`
#    nlmrt class object: x 
#    residual sumsquares =  6.2664e-08  on  21 observations
#        after  12    Jacobian and  13 function evaluations
#      name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      #gradient    JSingval   
#    d_ave             42.246            NA         NA         NA  #-7.269e-15    0.001428  
#    sigma            12.7429            NA         NA         NA   #2.568e-15   3.098e-19  
#    Ps              0.981517            NA         NA         NA   #9.211e-15   2.746e-20  
#    
#    $`3`
#    nlmrt class object: x 
#    residual sumsquares =  1.773e-07  on  21 observations
#        after  12    Jacobian and  13 function evaluations
#      name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      #gradient    JSingval   
#    d_ave             41.968            NA         NA         NA  #-6.438e-15    0.001798  
#    sigma            12.8561            NA         NA         NA   #2.173e-15   2.414e-19  
#    Ps              0.972988            NA         NA         NA   #8.534e-15   5.922e-20  

#    $`4`
#    nlmrt class object: x 
#    residual sumsquares =  2.5219e-07  on  21 observations
#        after  12    Jacobian and  13 function evaluations
#      name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      #gradient    JSingval   
#    d_ave            41.8532            NA         NA         NA  #-4.454e-15    0.001976  
#    sigma            12.9045            NA         NA         NA   #1.474e-15   3.443e-19  
#    Ps              0.974319            NA         NA         NA   #5.987e-15   3.124e-20  

#    attr(,"split_type")
#    [1] "data.frame"
#    attr(,"split_labels")
#      set
#    1   1
#    2   2
#    3   3
#    4   4
```

fitting coefficients are reasonable wolaa! But this time I realized that (@G. Grothendieck also pointed out later) it is impossible to predict new values after `nlxb` (why=? I don't know!)

```
predvals <- ldply(fit, .fun=predictvals, xvar="time", yvar="value",xrange=range(range)) # predict values
```

::you can find `predictvals` function from [here](https://rpubs.com/escott8908/RGC_Ch5_Scatter_Plots)

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
>     no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "nlmrt"

**There are NO! `coef` or `predict methods` for `"nlmrt"` class objects.**

## attempt 3

After following @G. Grothendieck another suggestion 
next I tried `wrapnls` from `nlmrt`.

because in this post he stated, 
[can-we-make-prediction-with-nlxb-from-nlmrt-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110555/can-we-make-prediction-with-nlxb-from-nlmrt-package?lq=1)

*"because nlmrt package does provide `wrapnls` which will run `nlmrt` and then `nls` so that an `"nls"` object results and then that object can be used with all the `"nls"` class methods.*

From the same `nlmrt` package still having trouble like at below

I give up to use `plyr` after my first [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909690/trouble-when-adding-3rd-fitting-parameter-in-nls) because loading `plyr` and `dplyr` is making my problem more complex. So I will stick with `dplyr` and use `do` function instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(nlmrt)
formula = value~Ps*(1-exp(-2*f*time*exp(-d)))*1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma))*exp(-(d-d_ave)^2/(2*sigma))*d_step

d_step <- 1
f <- 1e9
d <- 32

dffit = data_rep %>% group_by(set) %>%
  do(fit = wrapnls(formula ,
                data = .,
                start=c(d_ave=44,sigma=12,Ps=0.5),
                lower=c(d_ave=25,sigma=2,Ps=0.5),
                upper=c(d_ave=60,sigma=15,Ps=1),
                trace=TRUE))
```

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper) : 
>     singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

I returned back to where I started with this error. 
I guess I tried everything I can do, looking for relevant examples (though only 3 ), read book  and following the suggestions.

Comment: I said that the `nlmrt` package does not have a `predict` method for objects produced by `nlxb` but that the package provides `wrapnls` instead.  That is not the same as saying prediction is impossible.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I'm sorry if I misunderstand you. I meant that with `nlxb` it is impossible. By the way I found that I can get the fitting coefficients after doing `coeff <- ldply(fit, function(mod) c(coef(mod))) ` is that makes sense for predicting after `nlxb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nls2` from the nls2 package after `nlxb` like this (assuming `data_rep`,
`formula`, `d_step`, `f` and `d` from the question).  In order to make the example minimal we have eliminated dplyr and just show the computation for set == 2.

```
library(nlmrt)
library(nls2)

data_rep2 <- subset(data_rep, set == 2)

fit.nlxb <- nlxb(formula , data = data_rep2,
                start = c(d_ave = 44, sigma = 12, Ps = 0.5),
                lower = c(d_ave = 25, sigma = 2, Ps = 0.5),
                upper = c(d_ave = 60, sigma = 15, Ps = 1))

fit.nls <- nls2(formula, data = data_rep2, start = fit.nlxb$coefficients,
  algorithm = "brute-force")

identical(fit.nlxb$coefficients, coef(fit.nls))
## [1] TRUE
```

`fit.nls` is an `"nls"` class object with the same coefficients as `fit.nlxb` and we can use `fitted()` and `predict()` and all the other `"nls"` methods on it.

Comment: That's great. I understand that you just show the result for `set==2` for getting all set's fitting coefs what should I do?

Comment: Use `lapply(1:4, f)` where f outputs fit.nls for the appropriate subset of data_rep.

Comment: I will appreciate it if you can implement this to the  answer since my main question is fitting in groups. I couldn't understand from this short answer.

Comment: `f <- function(lv) { data_rep2 <- subset(data_rep, set == lv); fit.nlxb <- ....; fit.nls <- ...; fit.nls }` where you can get the right hand sides from the answer.

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote and did `lapply(1:4, f)` but got error `Error in -2 * f : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Call the function `fun` rather than `f` since `f` is already being used.

Comment: I changed function `f` to `fun` and rm(f) but now error turned out to be `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'f' not found`. I couldn't catch this error because I don't know where `f` was defined?

Comment: f is used in the formula and you deleted it.

Comment: I'm so sorry I just realized that. Thanks a lot. Now working perfectly. best regards!